# Symfony: choice_list with pre-selected values

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have an array field in my Entity called **Type** and I want to restrict the value that the user can specify for the field as this:

```
Type1      [] subtitle1        [] subtitle2         [] subtitle3

Type2      [] subtitle1        [] subtitle2         [] subtitle3
```

I managed to do this by creating `choice` form type and a little twig customization like this:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($entity)
                ->add('name', 'text')
                ->add('type', 'choice', array(
                    'multiple' => true,
                    'choice_list' => new myBundle\Form\Extension\CustomChoiceList($param1,$param2),
                    'label' => 'my Label',
                    'expanded' => true
                ));// CustomChoiceList extends ChoiceList
```

my issue now is when i have an entity i want to edit, how can i show the user the same form but with some of the checkboxes checked?

I checked `ChoiceList` and it's creating the checkboxes by using `ChoiceView` class which has no `checked` option only `label`, `value`, `data`

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the pre selected checkboxes with the "data" property

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($entity)
                ->add('name', 'text')
                ->add('type', 'choice', array(
                    'multiple' => true,
                    'choice_list' => new myBundle\Form\Extension\CustomChoiceList($param1,$param2),
                    'label' => 'my Label',
                    'expanded' => true,
                    'data' => 0 // Checks the first choise
                ));// CustomChoiceList extends ChoiceList
```