# Symfony form with multiple pre-selected checkboxes

Tags: forms, symfony, checkbox

I am currently developing a symfony project for which I need a form to edit an existing entity called `Location`.
One `Location` object can hold `0 to n` `Machines`. The form should contain multiple checkboxes, with preselected values depending on weather the entity `Location` already contains any `Machine` or not. If yes, preselect the checkbox, if not leave it empty.

The Location:

```
...
class Location
{    
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Machine", mappedBy="location")
     *  
     */
    private $machines;
...
```

The Machine:

```
...
class Machine
{

       /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Location", inversedBy="machines")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="location_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $location;  
   ...
```

I build the form like this:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($location)
 ->add('name', null , array( 'label' => 'Roomname: ', 'attr'=> array( 'placeholder'=>'Enter a name') ) )
 ->add('descr', null , array( 'label' => 'Description: ',  'attr'=> array( 'placeholder'=>'Enter a description') ) ) 
 ->add('machines', 'entity', array('class' => 'PRwissHostsBundle:Machine',
   'property' => 'name',
   'required' => false, 
   'expanded' => true,
   'multiple' => true, 

   ))
 ->getForm();
```

The code above results in a form with a couple of checkboxes with the entities name next to it. I want to pre select those checkboxes where the machines already are related to the location.

I have had a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20039511/symfony-choice-list-with-pre-selected-values) question, but unfortunatly the `"data" => x` only refers to one value.

Any ideas how I can accomplish this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add machines to Location entity in the controller, just before you initialize the form. Symfony form will automatically set values for checkboxes based on entity data.